# Checking for a null date before converting to java.sql.date from java.util.date

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno, java and MySQL.

I am trying to check if the date is `null` before converting it to `java.sql.Date` prior to writing it to the DB.

The following works provided the date is not null:

```
java.sql.Date sqlPackIn = new java.sql.Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());
```

So I am checking for null first:

```
//TODO check for a null date and handle it for dateBoxArchived and dateBoxPackOut
java.sql.Date sqlDateArchived = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
if (dateBoxArchived.getValue() != null){
    sqlDateArchived = dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime();
} else {
  sqlDateArchived = null;
  }
```

However, I am getting an error (`Type mismatch can not convert from long to date`) on `sqlDateArchived = (dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());`

and the recommended fix is to change it to long. I can not find any changed that resolves this.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: `new java.sql.Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime())` ??

Comment: how are you declaring `sqlDateArchived`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points:

- you never use the initialized value of current time, so don't code it
- you should pass the time of the existing date into the constructor
- you need only one line

Try this:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDateArchived = dateBoxArchived.getValue() == null ? null : new java.sql.Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

[Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returns a `long`. Presumably your `sqlDateArchived` is a `Date`. You can't put a `long` in a `Date`. Either change `sqlDateArchived` to be a long, or create a new `Date` like:

```
sqlDateArchived = new Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code 
`if (dateBoxArchived.getValue() != null){
    sqlDateArchived = dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime();`

convert last line to

```
sqlDateArchived = new Date(dateBoxArchived.getValue().getTime());`
```